# Retaining Form Values

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

How can we retain form values? 
The Server is written in PHP, and the action for the form is `"echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]".`

Without the use of cookies, PHP sessions, and without binding PHP variables to HTML Form values; **how can we possibly retain form values?**

Comment: Simply use AJAX for form submit, no need to retain anything or else you can go for HTML 5 storage e.g `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`

Comment: any idea on how to do it simply using pure AJAX, without jQuery

Comment: Check this out https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_httprequest

Answer (score 1):

- The simplest way with only HTML code is by adding the autocomplete="on" attribute to your form element.
- The best way is via embedding the PHP vars in the form.
  Try receiving/capturing the form values via the $_POST / $_GET super-globals. eg:

```html
// HTML

<form name="foo" action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] ?>" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" value="<?php echo $username ?>" />
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" value="<?php echo $password ?>" />
  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

// PHP

$username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

echo $username . $password;
```

Comment: i actually want the form to display the values that were submitted, even after it refreshes

Answer (score -1):

On submit just create a cookie witch contain all the data and if signIn or signUp is successful then unset the cookie but if error occurs then use that cookie and show data.

Create cookie for form

```
setcookie('form_data', $_POST, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

If error occurs store cookie in variable and use in form

```
$data = $_COOKIE['form_data'];
```

Display in form

```
<Input type='text' value='<?= isset($data['username'])?$data['username']:'' ?>
```